# My Minecraft worlds aren't loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ever since I tried to upgrade to 1.10, my Minecraft worlds won't come up. Sometimes I can get in the world but it says at the top "Minecraft _.__._ Not Responding". After it says that it gets off the game. SOMEONE HELP ME!!
This is what it says after it gets out of game,

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[17:23:49] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Sup3rGam3rSky
[17:23:49] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is <censored>)
[17:24:00] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[17:24:01] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[17:24:04] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[17:24:04] [Thread-6/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[17:24:04] [Thread-6/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[17:24:04] [Thread-6/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[17:24:04] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[17:24:23] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x512 textures-atlas
[17:25:08] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.8.6
[17:25:08] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[17:25:09] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[17:25:10] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 19%
[17:25:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 52%
[17:25:12] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 96%
[17:25:13] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 17, from 10
[17:25:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Sup3rGam3rSky[local:E:0aa54fc8] logged in with entity id 244 at (-511.0912092554738, 72.0, 346.7127868621491)
[17:25:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Sup3rGam3rSky joined the game

#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32744 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\gamer_000\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid2832.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\gamer_000\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\replay_pid2832.log
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

---

Someone please help!!

Comment: If you're allocating memory, don't, or allocate less, and if you aren't then do so. It seems to be a java runtime issue with memory allocation

Comment: The contents of `C:\Users\gamer_000\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid2832.log` would help. Try to use the default ressource pack or allocate more memory. A 512x512 pack needs a lot more than 32kb. How much RAM does your PC have?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your Java instance that's starting minecraft has hit its max memory.

How do you launch minecraft? If you're using a minecraft launcher, you can pass arguments to increase the allocation.

[Here's a stackoverflow post that might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications)

A few ways sugested on this post include:

1) Grab a 64 bit JRE

2) Allocate additional memory using the option parameter set `-d64 -Xms512m -Xmx4g`.

Comment: Problem here is that unless this guy is a computer wizard/programmer, he is not going to know how to launch minecraft with command line parameters... If he has already got a 64 bit installation, then this SO question isn't helping much.

Comment: Setting up more memory without knowing how much RAM is installed is a bad idea.

Comment: @AshwinGupta You can change launch parameters in the minecraft launcher

Comment: @Robin interesting I didn't know that. I figured you had to run the jar manually.

Comment: @dly he can easily check. System info tells you.

Comment: And I hope he does check it. :)

Comment: @dly is it just me or do you smell smoke? Wait, is that my CPU!!??

Answer (score 0):

While @anonymous coward did technically answer the question, I will explain how to fix it, step by step.

***Help for a copy of Windows***
 1. **Update Java.** You can click the link here:  [Java Update 8u101](http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=211968) 
 2. **Figure out how much ram you have.** To do this, press the windows key. Next, search `About Your PC` in windows 10 (to locate it manually, go to the app titled `SETTINGS` then click `About`). Scroll down until you see `Installed RAM` and `System type`. If your system type is `x86` or `32` then you will need to download the  [Windows x86](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) version. Once you install this, go to the search bar type configure Java, and run the program. For all the other versions then 8u101 `(1.8.1_00)` I believe or `(1.8.0_100)` click on them and click `remove`. Make sure 8u101 is enabled in both User and System and all other versions are removed. IF YOU ARE RUNNING WINDOWS 7, go to `control panel` , search `about` (top right ) and click on the green system. You will find the same two properties here (INSTALLED RAM & SYSTEM TYPE).
3. **Allocate more RAM** 
Next, we will do a conversion. Find the amount of your `INSTALLED RAM`, divide it by 4, and then multiply it by 1024. So if you had, say 8GB installed, you would get 2048.
Once you get this number, go to your minecraft launcher. Next, click `edit profile` and scroll down to `JVM ARGUMENTS` under `JAVA SETTINGS (ADVANCED)` and copy this into the section (Deleting all other arguments) `-Xmx256M -Xms256M` where 256 is the number you calculated.

I don't recommend 256M. Do 2048. or 1024.